# Can ant build apk updates gradle build apk in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, ant, phonegap-build

I have created an app(v1.0) using ant build in phonegap version = "cli-5.2.0" .For next update of my app (v1.1)  i have added a feature fcm it needs gradle build  so i have build using gradle

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
```

while iam trying to install(update) this app(v1.1) with my previous version of app(v1.0) its shows an err ***"App not installed."***

is there anyway to update my app?

Comment: It might help to see your config.xml file (minus identifying/secret information). Please post a gist or similar.

Comment: Here i have posted my config.xml file https://gist.github.com/pravinpsa/f3b0ba6849529056962a6f363d8235e2 Thank you